# Как убрать Title в Toolbar`e?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Как убрать заголовок приложения в `ToolBar`'е, который ставится по умолчанию.

Comment: `toolbar.setTitle(" ");` это для конкретного `Activity`.

Comment: Это не помогает) почему то

Comment: а между кавычками пробел есть?) попробуйте `toolbar.setTitle(null);`

Comment: Пробел между ними есть

Comment: Вот пробел то лучше убрать)

Comment: И без пробела и с `null`'ом тоже не работает

Comment: попробуйте `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`        `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`

Comment: Рад был помочь ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для того, чтобы *наверняка* убрать заголовок нужно:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```